# Know the path of origin in Angular 5

Tags: angular

```
{
    path: 'contacto-new-from-a',
    component: ContactoPopupComponent,
    outlet: 'popup'
},    {
    path: 'contacto-new-from-b',
    component: ContactoPopupComponent,
    outlet: 'popup'
},
```

I want two different behaviors for the same component, according to the original view that executes it.

I have some way of knowing in the destination component, the source path.

Thank you.

Comment: Why not to navigate by user action to specific route from where the user is rather than to analyse where user was and only then to navigate? You should be able to handle the router in the current view and its corresponding component ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if(this.route.snapshot.url[0].path === 'contacto-new-from-cliente') {
      this.fromCliente = true;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

While checking the URL is a working approach, I think that the most maintainable way and least error prone way to identify a route is to pass a fixed token value via your route.

In your route definition do :

```
{
   path: 'contacto-new-from-a',
   component: ContactoPopupComponent,
   outlet: 'popup',
   data: {
     token: 'routeA'
   }
},    
{
   path: 'contacto-new-from-b',
   component: ContactoPopupComponent,
   outlet: 'popup',
   data: {
     token: 'routeB'
   }
}
```

In your component

```
constructor(private route:ActivatedRoute, ...) {}

ngOnInit() {
    this.route.data.subscribe((data:{token:string}) => {
         switch(data.token) {
             case 'routeA':
                   // Your logic
                   ....;
             case 'routeB':
                   // Your logic
                   ....;
         }
    });
}
```

Note that this also caters for route changes when the component is not destroyed (eg navigating from `contacto-new-from-a` to `contacto-new-from-b`)

Answer (score -1):

```
  this.siteUrl = window.location.href;
  this.isBSite= this.siteUrl.indexOf('contacto-new-from-b') !== -1;
```

this is a hack to check the URL you are on

Or this

```
this.activatedRoute.snapshot.url.toString().indexOf('contacto-new-from-b') !== -1;
```

but you need to add the import

```
import {ActivatedRoute, Router} from '@angular/router';
```